# Returning Error Code from Controller with System.Web.Http

Tags: c#, rest, controller, system.web.http

I have a very light weight REST API that I wrote that validates a user.  I want to return the validation as a JSON object, which I can, but if there are missing arguments, I want to kick back an error with some information.  Here is my controller

```
    public class GraphAccessController : ApiController
    {
        private UserValidation _userValidation;
        private UserPermissions _userPermissions;
        string _application;

        public GraphAccessController()
        {
            _userValidation = new UserValidation();
            _userPermissions = new UserPermissions();
        }
        public object GetUserValidation(string application)
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(application))
            {
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
                //return new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
            }
            try
            {
                _application = application;
                ValidateUser(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), application);
                return _userValidation;
            }
            catch (HttpResponseException e)
            {
                string error = e.ToString();
                return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);

            }
        }....(other private calls for validation)
{
```

When the "application" is passed in, I get a nice JSON object back.  However, when I am trying to return an error to the user while checking for IsNullOrEmpty, if I just call with PostMan:

```
return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed)
```

the status is set to "405 Method Not Allowed" but I would like to pass down some text to indicate why it failed.  So I tried:

```
throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed);
```

and this just stops execution in my control.  So I did a return instead of throw I get a status of 200 (indicating everything was fine) but the JSON header data:

> > {
> >         "Response": {
> >             "Version": {
> >                 "_Major": 1,
> >                 "_Minor": 1,
> >                 "_Build": -1,
> >                 "_Revision": -1
> >             },
> >             "Content": null,
> >             "StatusCode": 405,
> >             "ReasonPhrase": "Method Not Allowed",
> >             "Headers": [],
> >             "RequestMessage": null,
> >             "IsSuccessStatusCode": false
> >         },
> >         "Message": "Processing of the HTTP request resulted in an exception. Please see the HTTP response returned by the 'Response'
> >     property of this exception for details.",
> >         "Data": {},
> >         "InnerException": null,
> >         "TargetSite": null,
> >         "StackTrace": null,
> >         "HelpLink": null,
> >         "Source": null,
> >         "HResult": -2146233088 }

As you can see from the code in the catch I am also trying to do the same type of thing.  How do you return a StatusCode with corresponding information text to the caller so they can check the status and if it isn't 200, check the body for error text?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results ? I think that using `HttpResponseMessage` is the proper way to handle that you want.

Comment: I looked at this and tried with this code:

  string error = "Application cannot be empty";
  HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotImplemented, Encoding.Unicode);
                response.Content = new StringContent(error);
                return response;

But when I do I get this error: 

  "ExceptionMessage": "Method not found: 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage System.Web.Http.ApiController.get_Request()'.",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try returning a content response with the desired HttpStatusCode like this:

```
catch (HttpResponseException e)
        {
            string error = e.ToString();
            return Content(HttpStatusCode.MethodNotAllowed, error);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you!  This did it.  I wasn't returning content.